# How to parse an anonymous array in JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string which I'm already parsing. One particular property is an array similar to:

```
[[1537488000000,50500],[1537574400000,54028],[1537660800000,60447],[1537747200000,60542]]
```

The above is the JSON string, however the content above is contained within a JToken object.

How do I parse the JToken values into an instance of a concrete class?

Comment: It's just an array of an array of numbers, right? Did you try deserializing to that? Ex, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<long>>(json)`

Comment: It should deserialize to `List<List<long>>` just fine.

Comment: @JonathonChase Edited my question. The content is within a JToken object.

Comment: What do you mean "the content is within a JToken object"? Show your code.

Comment: @mason https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm just find out for yourself?

Comment: @DanRayson I know what  JToken is, but the point is that the code isn't in the question, thus the question isn't complete.

Comment: @mason I feel that the question was complete enough to actually get a correct answer.  That's enough for me.  EDIT:  I should add I do appreciate you trying to improve the question, just was maybe a little over eager in doing so.

Comment: @DanRayson Good for you, but I have years of experiencing answering questions on Stack Overflow, and often seeing the exact code being used reveals that the question was misleading or reveals some other misunderstanding on the part of the asker.

Comment: @mason Yes, but be polite when asking people to do so.  Please.

Comment: @DanRayson What exactly was impolite here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181367/discussion-between-dan-rayson-and-mason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize it as a 2d array:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<long[][]>("[[1537488000000,50500],[1537574400000,54028],[1537660800000,60447],[1537747200000,60542]]")
```

Or, as a jagged 2d and then convert it into a dictionary of long long:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<long[][]>("[[1537488000000,50500],[1537574400000,54028],[1537660800000,60447],[1537747200000,60542]]")
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1])
```

If you received this as a `JToken`, use this instead:

```
JToken token = ...   
token
    .ToObject<long[][]>()
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```